# What is the starting value of saturation?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When you spawn in a new world do you have the max 20 points of saturation? Pretty basic question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](//minecraft.gamepedia.com/Hunger#Mechanics):

> *foodSaturationLevel*: The player's current saturation level, which determines how fast the hunger level depletes and is controlled by the kinds of food the player has eaten. Its maximum value always equals *foodLevel*'s value and decreases with the hunger level. **Its initial value on world creation is 5.**

(bolding mine)

This means that, when you spawn in a new world, your hidden saturation bar is approximately one quarter full.

I verified this claim myself by creating a new world and running `/data get entity @s foodSaturationLevel`, which produced `5.0f` as the wiki suggested.